# autoconfiguration exclusions not working anymore when migrating from Sprint Boot 2.7 to 3.1.4

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jakarta-migration

We are trying to migrate our backend from **Spring Boot 2.7** to **3.1.4** and encoutering issues with autoconfiguration exclusions.

Basically it's a multi module project and we have some rest controller tests using stubbed classes for the DB

A litte rundown

**Spring Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.contract.backend")
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.contract.backend.*"})
public class Application {}
```

The controller **SubscriberContractController** is calling a **SubscriberContractService** service which is calling a Dao interface **SubscriberContractDao** (in persistence module)

The interface is implemented by the regular DAO class **SubscriberContractDBDao** (itself calling a JpaRepository)

```
package com.contract.backend.contract.persistence;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Profile("!stubdb")
public class SubscriberContractDBDao implements SubscriberContractDao {}
```

and by the stubbed implementation **SubscriberContractStubDao** returning static data

```
package com.contract.backend.contract.persistence;

public class SubscriberContractStubDao implements SubscriberContractDao {}
```

and we have the following configuration class (in application module) for the stubbed DAO

```
package com.contract.backend.application.configuration;

@Configuration
@Profile("stubdb")
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.contract.backend"}
)
public class StubConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SubscriberContractDao subscriberStubDao() {
        return new SubscriberContractStubDao();
    }
}
```

In the test/resources part of the application module we define our exclusion configuration to be used with the "stubdb" profile **bootstrap-stubdb.properties** (line break for easy read)

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

The test itself is using MockMvc

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"stubdb, DEV})
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class})
class SubscriberContractControllerDocTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                      RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)
                        .uris()
                        .withScheme("https")
                        .withPort(443))
                .build();
    }
    
    // Test example
    @Test
    void should_retrieve_sub_contract_by_id() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/subscriber-contract/{id}", 2)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("subscriber-contract-by-id",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                        pathParameters(
                                parameterWithName("id").description("The id of the subscriber contract we want to retrieve")
                        ),
                        responseFields(
                                subscriberContractDtosFields()
                        )));
    }
}
```

On Sprint Boot 2.7 this is working fine, nothing related to a real DB or anything JPA in instanciated, the stubbed DAO is called.

After migrating to Spring Boot 3.1.4 (with no other issues) we get the following:

Keeping the configuration as is we get the following error when launching any tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@379b4e86 testClass = com.contract.backend.application.contract.controller.SubscriberContractControllerDocTest,\
 locations = [], classes = [com.contract.backend.application.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["stubdb", "dev"], propertySourceLocations = [], \
 propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], \
 contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@e350b40, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@13e344d,\
 org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@740cae06,\
 org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, \
 org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@1ca3b418, \
 org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@85e8c2c7],\
 resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
 
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:688)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
```

However if we remove the **HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration** exclusion:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
```

All GET tests (not using transactions) start to work but the ones hitting a @Transactional tries to connect to the real (dev) DB through an entityManager instance and we can even see HikariPool is instanciated

```
023-10-13 16:21:38.359  INFO 15604 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext [--/--] : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2023-10-13 16:21:38.359  INFO 15604 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  [--/--] : Initializing Servlet ''
2023-10-13 16:21:38.360  INFO 15604 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  [--/--] : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-10-13 16:21:38.373  INFO 15604 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       [--/--] : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-13 16:21:39.378 ERROR 15604 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        [--/--] : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection refused: no further information
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:137)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.<init>(StandardClient.java:99)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:70)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:101)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
[...]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
    
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.contract.backend.contract.service.SubscriberContractService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createOrUpdate(<generated>)
    at com.contract.backend.application.contract.controller.SubscriberContractController.createOrUpdate(SubscriberContractController.java:123)
    at com.contract.backend.application.contract.controller.SubscriberContractController.create(SubscriberContractController.java:103)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    [...]
    at com.contract.backend.application.contract.controller.SubscriberContractControllerDocTest.should_create_subscriber_contract(SubscriberContractControllerDocTest.java:234)
```

In that case, here **SubscriberContractService.createOrUpdate** is annotated with **@Transactional**
The odd things is that the GET tests without transactions hit the SubscriberContractStubDao just fine and not the SubscriberContractDBDao ...

So we're lost... once again this worked fine in Spring Boot 2.7 without issues (including the exclusion of **HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration**)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, only thing needed was adding the following exclusion to the previous ones:
`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`